# Output vertex stream with Blender

Tags: blender

I'm looking to output a stream of the vertices, UVs and normals of an animated object (with clothing/softbody physics) to a file.

Is this possible with Blender? If not, is there another modelling application which can do that?

If it is possible, what such exporting of vertices called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to write a script with the Python Blender API: https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_2/  This requires a lot of time to do.

If you want to use a common format, you could export your mesh with the export scripts in blender (to .obj, to .md5 etc...).

Comment: I think obj or md5 will suffice. I just looked it up and apparently it's not very hard to bake the soft body physics in a model.

Comment: @KajToet: the api becomes really hard (bad documented) when you try to export the animations. If you want to export the skeletons, I didn't find the way to get the keyframes of the bones in the skeleton.

Comment: Luckely I don't need the skeletons, a composed model (I don't know the lingo yet, sorry) would work best for me. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

How you export will depend mostly on where you want the data to go.

*.obj* is a simple mesh object file while *.mdd* can contain an animated mesh - basically exports the mesh for each frame.

If you need to export in a custom format it isn't hard to get the mesh data to export. The `obj.to_mesh()` provides a copy of the mesh data with all modifiers and simulations applied.

```
import bpy, bmesh

scn = bpy.context.scene
obj = bpy.context.active_object
me = obj.to_mesh(scn, True, 'RENDER')

print('Vertices--')
for v in me.vertices:
    print(v.index,':',end=' ')
    for l in v.co:
        print(l,end=',')
    print()

print('Edges--')
for e in me.edges:
    print(e.index,':',end=' ')
    for v in e.vertices:
        print(v,end=',')
    print()

print('Faces--')
for f in me.polygons:
    print(f.index,':',end=' ')
    for v in f.vertices:
        print(v,end=',')
    print()

del me
```

You can get blender specific help with python scripts at [blender.stackexchange](http://blender.stackexchange.com).